# cell to overflow text but still consider linebreaks inside text

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I have a cell that contains multiline text. Some lines are pretty long. I would like the text to overflow the cell boarder but at the same time respect the line breaks from the text and I need the cell height to be auto-fit.

Is that possible?

The cell layout is predefined by content above. I can't use merged cell to make the cell wide enough because then the auto-fit height does not work anymore.
When I activate line wrap it also wraps long lines. I would like the wrap only where "newlines" are in the text.

I created an picture of what I want: [Overflow the cell unless there is a newline  - then autogrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHyrz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, to see multiple lines in a cell you need to have
*Wrap text* enabled for that cell, which precludes text overflow.

As far as I know, what you ask is not possible.

Comment: I was already afraid of that. Thanks for confirming anyway!